# Prove $\lim_{x\to -\infty} x^n = \infty$ if $n>0$ is even.

Tags: real-analysis, limits, solution-verification

These kinds of proofs never feel rigorous to me, so I might be missing something. Here's what I did:

For all $M<0$, if $x<0$,

$x^n > 0 > M$

For all $M\ge0$, if $x<-\root{n}\of{M}$,

$x^n > M$

And that's it. To me, this does not feel right. Do I need to expand more on proving that $x^n > 0$ for the first part, or maybe that $-\root{n}\of{M}$ even exists, or that $x<-\root{n}\of{M}$ results in $x^n > M$?

I have this feeling for any proof I do regarding "if $n$ is even/odd" where $n$ is a power. What am I missing?

Comment: First things first, what is your definition of $\lim_{x\to -\infty} f(x)= \infty$?

Comment: @ashK Isn't the standard definition just that for all M, there is an N such that if x is less than N, then f(x) is greater than M? I didn't think I would have to write the definition down.

Answer (score 1):

I would definately go for the route of proving that $x^n$ for $x<0$ and for positive even integer $n$, results always being positive. This is a stepping stone for showing the "unboundedness" itself, and lends for easier solutions to show that the function of $x^n$ is not bounded by any given $M$, from which you can easily conclude that $x^n$ really diverges.

To be a bit blunt, you are now only proving that $x^n$ is only greater than some $M$ given that some conditions are met, for the relationship of $x$ and $M$. Tautologous, I would say.

What is missing, is that you have tie the strings to show that given **any** $M$, there always exists a point(s) of $x^n$ that are larger than the given $M$. And for this purpose, I would prove that the $x^n$ is always positive with the given conditions, and it's also clearly continuous and increasing, which grants a possibility to choose sufficient $x_M$ to get $x_M^n>M$.

In my opinion going through even and odd $n$ is unnecessary, unless that is a way you want to show the positiveness of the $x^n$.

Comment: So would you say my positive M case is accurate, I don't need to expand on that? All I need to do is prove that x^n is positive?

Comment: @NathanRocha I would say it is true, definitely, but it does not take you much further. You need to prove that $x^n$ is always positive and that no matter how large $M$ you choose, there will values of $x^n$ being larger than the chosen $M$. One way to do it, is that you firstly show $x^n>0$ for the given conditons of even $n$ and $x<0$, and secondly that then there's a contradiction if you try to get epsilon-delta proof for boundedness, from which you show the unboundedness and therefore the divergence.